# Have gstreamer pipeline run at reading/decoding speed when using appsink

Tags: python, gstreamer

If I create a simple pipeline to read an mkv file into a fakesink, it will run as fast as the machine can read and process the file:

```
$ time gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=bar.mkv ! matroskademux ! fakesink
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is PREROLLING ...
Pipeline is PREROLLED ...
Setting pipeline to PLAYING ...
New clock: GstSystemClock
Got EOS from element "pipeline0".
Execution ended after 0:00:00.000402211
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Setting pipeline to READY ...
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
Freeing pipeline ...

real    0m0.020s
user    0m0.016s
sys     0m0.004s
```

The file in question is 5 seconds long, but this runs in a fraction of a second. Now if I want to have the same inside a program, and use an `appsink` instead of the `fakesink`, this runs at playback speed. Consider this simple Python program:

```py
import sys
import gi
gi.require_version('Gst', '1.0')
from gi.repository import Gst
from gi.repository import GObject


def on_message(bus, msg, loop):
    if msg.type == Gst.MessageType.EOS:
        print("End of stream")
        loop.quit()

    return True


def new_sample(sink, data):
    sample = sink.emit('pull-sample')
    return Gst.FlowReturn.OK


def main():
    Gst.init(None)

    loop = GObject.MainLoop()

    pipeline = Gst.Pipeline()
    src = Gst.ElementFactory.make('filesrc')
    demux = Gst.ElementFactory.make('matroskademux')
    sink = Gst.ElementFactory.make(sys.argv[1])

    src.set_property('location', 'bar.mkv')

    if sys.argv[1] == 'appsink':
        sink.set_property('emit-signals', True)
        sink.connect('new-sample', new_sample, None)

    pipeline.add(src)
    pipeline.add(demux)
    pipeline.add(sink)

    src.link(demux)

    def pad_added(element, pad):
        stream = pad.query_caps(None).to_string()
        pad.link(sink.get_static_pad('sink'))
    demux.connect('pad-added', pad_added)

    bus = pipeline.get_bus()
    bus.add_signal_watch()
    bus.connect('message', on_message, loop)

    pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.PLAYING)
    loop.run()
    pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.NULL)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

If I run it with a fakesink, it's still very fast:

```
$ time python ./foo.py fakesink
End of stream

real    0m0.095s
user    0m0.078s
sys     0m0.018s
```

But if I use the appsink, it takes just over 5 seconds:

```
$ time python ./foo.py appsink
End of stream

real    0m5.068s
user    0m0.099s
sys     0m0.014s
```

which shows gstreamer is synchronizing the frames so they run at the framerate specified in the file. Can we get the `fakesink` behavior with `appsink`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This behavior is controlled via the the sink's `sync` property. By default the `fakesink` has this set to `false`. Set this property to `true` to have the same behavior as the `appsink`.

```sh
$ time gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=bar.mkv ! matroskademux ! fakesink sync=true
```